# Send Push Notifications to Ionic app with TTL

Tags: php, android, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification

I need to send push notification to ionic android app with a `TTL`. I used the PHP code to send push mentioned in following git (https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017).

And I used both following end points
(https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send & https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) to send push notification. But Push notification was sent after the `TTL`.

I added this line to destroy after `TTL`.

```
$msg = array
(
'body' => 'This is a message sent from my http server',
'title' => 'From server side',
'priority' => 'high',
'sound' => 'default',
'time_to_live' => 3600
);
```

Above code is also mentioned in the reply of above git code by "FernandoFactor".

How could I resolve this problem?